# Приложение приостанавливается при запуске

Tags: android

Возникла проблема когда запускаю приложение с эмулятора все работает, но при запуске на других телефонах приложение приостанавливается, с чем может быть связана эта ошибка? Первоначально я думал, что это из-за разницы версий андроид(тестировал на 5.1 и 6.0)

Вот код манифеста:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.jone1.graciaonline">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <meta-data android:name="android.security.net.config"
        android:resource="@xml/network_security_config" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Gracia online"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".fragment14"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            </intent-filter>
            android:label="@string/about_title">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer/com.example.jone1.graciaonline.LoginActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.example.jone1.graciaonline.LoginActivity" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer-1/lib/arm64,
>   /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]] at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2623)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2782)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1521)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6228) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794) Caused
>   by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.example.jone1.graciaonline.LoginActivity" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer-1/lib/arm64,
>   /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]] at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1079) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2613)
>   ... 9 more   Ещё

Comment: А почему у вас для всех Activity есть <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

Comment: И да, покажите Traceback ошибки. Мы не экстрасенсы

Comment: @danilshik Добавил

Comment: В manifest'e попробуйте поменять путь в name=".LoginActivity"

Answer (score 1):

Если судить по ошибке, то ваша `LoginActivity` находится не в корне `package` приложения, значит вы не можете написать ".LoginActivity". Если она у вас в каталоге глубже, то вам нужно указать этот каталог, например, если путь такой: com > bla > blabla > activities > LoginActivity, то:

```
android:name=".activities.LoginActivity"
```

*P.S Первая точка это package приложения*